# Page Routing with Tabs Template Ionic not Working

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Good Morning All,
Im using ionic 5 and using a tabs template and I created non tabs pages that I want buttons to link to and when I do I'm using the Routing module, I get back a error. I get theses below

ERROR in src/app/hours/hours.module.ts(18,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HoursPage'.
[ng]     src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './hoursnew.page'.

Heres my Tab1.Page.Ts Code below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HoursnewPage } from './hoursnew.page';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  hours(){
  this.router.navigate(['/hoursnew']);
  }

}
```

Let me know what I did wrong here thanks
Adam

Comment: Add your routing as well ...

Answer (score -1):

```
import statement is not correct  change it to valid path

import { HoursnewPage } from './hoursnew.page';
```

should be

```
import { HoursnewPage } from 'src/app/hoursnew/hoursnew.page';  // it should be valid
```